# After adding redux-persist, I can no longer get the state of the redux store

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-persist

I have looked for solutions to this for two day now, and haven't found anyone with the exact same problem. I assume I am doing something stupid.

I can no longer reference my redux store after adding redux-persist. It is there. I can see it in the redux dev tools. Also when I use a debugger and hover over state, I can see it. But when I attempt to pull out "trips" (a property of the object of the state), It won't let me and says "Property 'trips' does not exist on type 'PersistPartial'".

```
import { store } from "redux/store";
...
const { trips } = store.getState();
```

Doing this worked before adding redux-persist. But now it give me that error stated above, since store now is type: "Store<PersistPartial, any> & {
dispatch: unknown;
}"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is like me and had this issue. The solution was to not use "store.getState()" anymore and pass the state of the store through as a parameter to the action, after retrieving it using "useSelector" imported from "react-redux".